# Серийный номер

Tags: php

Делаю программу, привязанную к компу, но на двух хостингах функции `sybase_fetch_row()` и связанных с sybase нет. Может, ещё как то можно сделать привязку?

Comment: Может, я чего не понял... А какая связь между Sybase и привязке к компьютеру?

Comment: Профессионально лицензионную защиту делают с помощью [ion cube](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140159/).

Answer (score 1):

Sybase - это база данных. То, что какая-то база данных не поддерживается на каком-то хостинге, никак не влияет на привязку программы к компьютеру. Используй базу данных MySQL, она на всех виртуальных хостингах есть. Функция `sybase_fetch_row()` будет называться `mysql_fetch_row()`.